# jQuery : How to do validation in jquery before submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a form bootstrap form like below

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="" role="form" class="ajax">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="userName"></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrName">
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="passWrd"></label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passWrd">
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="loginButton">Login</button>      
    </div>
```

I am doing form validation in my jquery as below. How do I call `submit()` method  in my code? i.e how do I make ajax call to submit the form content after validation in the jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function validateInput(id) {
    if($("#"+id).val()==null || $("#"+id).val()=="") {
      var div=$("#"+id).closest("div");
      div.addClass("has-error");
      return false;
    } else {
      var div=$("#"+id).closest("div");
      div.removeClass("has-error");
      div.addClass("has-success");
      return false;
    }     
  }
  $(#loginButton).click(function() {
enter code here
    if(!validateInput("userName"))
    {
      return false;
    }

    if(!validateInput("passWrd"))
    {
      return false;
    }

  });

});
```

How do i call $.ajax after i complete the validation in my above code?

P.S : I am not supposed to use any jquery plugin for the validation.

Comment: Keep in mind, your validateInput() is currently not returning anything, so using that in and if/else statement won't work..

Comment: When validating a string, trim the input box to be sure the user did not just add spaces `$("#"+id).val().trim() == ""`

Comment: You need to return true in the else block of your function. This is missing from your code. Plus you should be using both the if conditions together using && so that if any of these fails you can can stop the submit.

Answer (score 0):

This code will check EVERY input field.

```
$(#loginButton).click(function() {
  if (!$.trim($("input").val()) {     //check ALL input fields, see if they have valid (non-falsy) values
    alert("some input needs fixin'!");
  } else {
    submit();  //since you mentioned this in your post
    $.ajax({});//or make an ajax call, or put it inside of a function and call that, the possibilities are endless..
  }
});
```

Comment: I have to validate more than one properties. I have updated my question. Kindly check and reply to me.Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#loginForm').submit()` will submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Although this can be done in several ways, using your example, I can see that you are already returning false on validation failure. Return true from the end of your validateInput() method.

```
function validateInput(item) {
  var div=item.closest("div");
  if(item.val()==null || item.val()=="") {        
    div.addClass("has-error");
    return false;
  } else {
    div.removeClass("has-error");
    div.addClass("has-success");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then, in the click event handler, check the returned value and call the form.submit()

```
$('#loginButton').click(function() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('.form-control').each(function(){
      isValid &= validateInput($(this));
  });
  if (isValid)
  {
      var data = $('#loginForm').serialize();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'your endpoint',
         type: 'POST',
         data: data
      });
  }
});
```

to submit the form.

Here's a working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/r5cysDNAKq7OczigjIfJ?p=preview).

Comment: I have to validate more than one properties. I have updated my question. Kindly check and reply to me.Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: We are working with a lot of assumptions here but assuming that all your input fields have the 'form-control' class, the above code should work fine. We could change the selector to 'input' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validateInput(id) {
  var element = $("#"+id);
  var success = false;
    if (element.val() == null || element.val().trim() == "") {
      element.closest("div").addClass("has-error");
    } else {
      var div = element .closest("div");
      div.removeClass("has-error");
      div.addClass("has-success");
      success = true;
    }     
  return success;
  }
  $(#loginButton).click(function() {
    if (validateInput("usrName")) {
         $('#loginForm').submit()
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I have to validate more than one properties. I have updated my question. Kindly check and reply to me.Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-class="{ 'form-group has-error has-feedback' : datos.campo.$invalid && !datos.campo.$pristine, 'form-group has-success has-feedback' : datos.campo.$valid}">
    <label class="control-label" for="campo">Modelo</label>
        <input ng-model="data.campo" name="campo" type="text" class="form-control" id="campo" required>
        <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback':datos.campo.$invalid && !datos.campo.$pristine, 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback':datos.campo.$valid}"></span>
    <span ng-show="datos.campo.$invalid && !datos.campo.$pristine" class="col-md-8 center badge badge-danger">Incorrecto</span>
</div>
```

Con Angular JS es mas facil validar campos, [Checa este link](http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/xFcdI?editors=1010)

Answer (score -1):

You could use [this](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin. This is the best and easiest to use plugin I have found for validating a form.